# How to transpose rows to columns in SQL or SSIS having dynamic values

Tags: sql, sql-server, excel, ssis, transpose

I have following table where daily data is saved:

[image: Data generated by SQL Query]

I need to read the last 7 days of data and transpose the rows to columns to save it in Excel Report. I am trying to automate this with SSIS. 
Note that here the dates which will behave as columns after transpose will be dynamic based on last seven days so I cannot use static column names in pivot function.
The desired output will look like this:

[image: Desired output format]

Please advice how can I accomplish the output either through MS-SQL or SSIS. Thanks in advance. Following is table schema and sample data:

```
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#PriorityTrends') IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE #PriorityTrends  

CREATE TABLE #PriorityTrends (
    CountDate DATETIME,
    [Priority 1] INT,
    [Priority 2] INT,
    [Priority 3] INT,
    [Priority 4] INT,
    [Priority 5] INT,
    Total INT
    )

INSERT INTO #PriorityTrends
VALUES ('6/24/2014', 163, 235, 741, 265, 1932, 1404)

INSERT INTO #PriorityTrends
VALUES ('6/25/2014', 174, 368, 775, 256, 2634, 1573)

INSERT INTO #PriorityTrends
VALUES ('6/26/2014', 201, 448, 703, 270, 2717, 1622)

INSERT INTO #PriorityTrends
VALUES ('6/27/2014', 140, 464, 612, 257, 1776, 1473)

INSERT INTO #PriorityTrends
VALUES ('6/30/2014', 106, 333, 1274, 311, 1480, 2024)

INSERT INTO #PriorityTrends
VALUES ('7/1/2014', 164, 834, 1533, 1145, 10483, 3676)

INSERT INTO #PriorityTrends
VALUES ('7/2/2014', 136, 378, 1421, 391, 9018, 2326)
```

Comment: It can be done with SQL server itself. You don't need the power of SSIS for this. Please put your original table in text form instead of image and I can help. You need to use 2 things - pivoting and dynamic sql to achieve the results.

Comment: Can't you just copy paste the result set from management studio and post it here ?

Comment: That's what I did. But it is showing in this weird format. Sorry but I don't know how can I put it more elegant way.

Comment: can you give me the sql to create table and sample rows ? I am not going to type all this.

Comment: See my update in the question. I have provided sample over there. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to do it with dynamic SQL and pivoting, however it got very long but it will suffice my requirements. If anybody can give suggestion to optimize this it would be welcoming.
[This article helped me.](http://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/2783/script-to-create-dynamic-pivot-queries-in-sql-server/)

Below is the query which worked for me:

```
    IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#PriorityData') IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE #PriorityData 

create table #PriorityData(
  CountDate date,
  [Priority 1] int,
  [Priority 2] int,
  [Priority 3] int,
  [Priority 4] int,
  [Priority 5] int,
  Totals int
  )

insert into #PriorityData
select * from (select top 7 * from PriorityTrends p 
               order by p.CountDate desc) as temp
order by temp.CountDate

select * from #PriorityData

DECLARE @columns NVARCHAR(MAX), @sql NVARCHAR(MAX)

SET @columns = N''

SELECT @columns += N', ' + QUOTENAME(CountDate)
  FROM (SELECT p.CountDate FROM #PriorityData AS p) AS x

SET @sql = N'
SELECT ''Priority 1'' AS Priority, ' + STUFF(@columns, 1, 2, '') + '
FROM
(
  SELECT CountDate, [Priority 1] from #PriorityData
) AS j
PIVOT
(
  SUM([Priority 1]) FOR CountDate IN ('
  + STUFF(REPLACE(@columns, ', p1.[', ',['), 1, 1, '')
  + ')
) AS p1
UNION ALL
SELECT ''Priority 2'' AS Priority, ' + STUFF(@columns, 1, 2, '') + '
FROM
(
  SELECT CountDate, [Priority 2] from #PriorityData
) AS j
PIVOT
(
  SUM([Priority 2]) FOR CountDate IN ('
  + STUFF(REPLACE(@columns, ', p2.[', ',['), 1, 1, '')
  + ')
) AS p2
UNION ALL
SELECT ''Priority 3'' AS Priority, ' + STUFF(@columns, 1, 2, '') + '
FROM
(
  SELECT CountDate, [Priority 3] from #PriorityData
) AS j
PIVOT
(
  SUM([Priority 3]) FOR CountDate IN ('
  + STUFF(REPLACE(@columns, ', p3.[', ',['), 1, 1, '')
  + ')
) AS p3
UNION ALL
SELECT ''Priority 4'' AS Priority, ' + STUFF(@columns, 1, 2, '') + '
FROM
(
  SELECT CountDate, [Priority 4] from #PriorityData
) AS j
PIVOT
(
  SUM([Priority 4]) FOR CountDate IN ('
  + STUFF(REPLACE(@columns, ', p4.[', ',['), 1, 1, '')
  + ')
) AS p4
UNION ALL
SELECT ''Priority 5'' AS Priority, ' + STUFF(@columns, 1, 2, '') + '
FROM
(
  SELECT CountDate, [Priority 5] from #PriorityData
) AS j
PIVOT
(
  SUM([Priority 5]) FOR CountDate IN ('
  + STUFF(REPLACE(@columns, ', p5.[', ',['), 1, 1, '')
  + ')
) AS p5
UNION ALL
SELECT ''Totals'' AS Priority, ' + STUFF(@columns, 1, 2, '') + '
FROM
(
  SELECT CountDate, [Totals] from #PriorityData
) AS j
PIVOT
(
  SUM([Totals]) FOR CountDate IN ('
  + STUFF(REPLACE(@columns, ', t.[', ',['), 1, 1, '')
  + ')
) AS t'
PRINT @sql
EXEC sp_executesql @sql
```